# Porque não existe Lookbehind em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript, lookbehind

Fiquei sabendo que não existe o *group construct lookbehind* em Regex's feitas em JavaScript então me surgiram algumas dúvidas como:

- Porque não existe? 
  Existe algum motivo que a torne incompatível c/ a linguagem ou desnecessária?
- Caso for desnecessária, existe alguma alternativa para o uso de lookbehind que cause o mesmo resultado?
- Porque somente essa linguagem não possui esse *group construct*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Atualização

[Lookbehind](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) foi [aceito](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md) nas [especificação do ECMAScript](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) em 2018. Até agora foi implementada somente em [V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/). Então se você é um desenvolvedor de ambientes restritos a somente Chrome (como [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)), ou [Node](https://nodejs.org/), você já pode usar essa asserção, evite caso sua aplicação seja multi browser, a seguir uma lista de plataformas que aceitam Lookbehind.

Plataformas suportadas:

- ✔[V8](https://developers.google.com/v8/)

  - ✔[Google Chrome 62.0](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4545)
  - ✔[Node.js 6.0 somente com flag e 9.0 com/sem flag](https://node.green/)
- ❌[Mozilla Firefox (SpiderMonkey) está trabalhando nisso](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1225665)
- ❌[Microsoft estava trabalhando com isso no Chakra](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/3448), porém a próxima versão do Edge será feita com base Chromium e assim, suportará a asserção
- ❌[Apple Safari (Webkit) está trabalhando nisso](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=174931)

Uso do positive lookbehind:

```js
console.log(
  "$9.99  €8.47".match(/(?<=\$)\d+(\.\d*)?/) // Encontra "9.99"
);
```

Uso do negative lookbehind:

```js
console.log(
  "$9.99  €8.47".match(/(?<!\$)\d+(?:\.\d*)/) // Encontra "8.47"
);
```

- [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent)

---

### OLD

Depois de algum tempo estudando o assunto cheguei nas seguintes conclusões:

> Porque não existe (`negative/positive lookbehind`)?

Parece que Brendan Eich [não sabia de sua existencia na época](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2010-November/012165.html), pois o Netscape foi feito em uma versão antiga de *Perl*.
Mesmo assim após algum tempo foram feitas algumas tentativas de implementação, porém sem sucesso devido a complexidade de implementação, pois as Expressões Regulares em EcmaScript funcionam a partir de [backtracking](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backtracking-in-regular-expressions), que é necessário também para o uso de lookbehind, então caso o uso de lookbehind fosse incorreto poderia acarretar alguns problemas como [backtracking catastrófico](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

---

> Existe algum motivo que a torne incompatível c/ a linguagem ou desnecessária?

Ela não é incompatível nem impossível de ser implementada, porém ainda não foi apresentada uma maneira de implementação que seja performática, contudo existe uma proposta que já está no estágio 3 de implementação para que o uso de *lookbehind* seja compatível com EcmaScript.
Não diria que é desnecessária, pois [existe ganho em performance ao utilizar o *group construct lookahead* ou *lookbehind*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/best-practices)

---

> [...] existe alguma alternativa para o uso de lookbehind que cause o mesmo resultado?

**Se não levarmos em consideração a performance**, você pode chegar aos mesmos resultados utilizando múltiplos grupos de captura ou até *lookahead's* na mesma expressão.
Como você pode ver nesse [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376238/javascript-regex-look-behind-alternative).

---

> Porque somente essa linguagem não possui esse group construct?

Como já foi citado é realmente difícil fazer algo performático e que apresente um comportamento estável quando usada com outros *tokens* e *group constructs*, porém como já está em estágio 3 sua implementação em EcmaScript, acredito que isso não será verdade por muito tempo.